# Kerberos for multihop remoting powershell

Tags: powershell, administration, kerberos

I am trying to set up a remote powershell session to a sharepoint server in order to do remote management. I am running as a user with full mgmt rights at the sharepoint server

If I use Credssp and enter credentials, I can connect and run sharepoint cmds

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName spserver -ConfigurationName PSv2 -Credential domain\adminuser -Authentcation Credssp
```

But I don't want the admin user(s) to have to enter their credentials once more when they are already authenticated at the admin server.

So I am trying to use the following connection cmd

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName spserver -Authentication Kerberos -ConfigurationName PSv2
```

When attempting to run powershell cmds I get the error "cannot access the local farm"

An error is logged on the sharepoint server,

> SQL database login for 'SP_Config' on instance 'spserver' failed.
>   Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

So I am assuming that the credentials did not pass further that the first hop to the server.

Most of the tutorials on remoting seem to focus on Credssp, I can't find much on how to troubleshoot Kerberos for this purpose. Any pointers to good information on this?

**UPDATE**

I have found some information that seem to indicate that *Powershell remoting does not support multiple hops using Kerberos!* I'd be happy if anyone could confirm this

> "Windows PowerShell remoting does not support Kerberos delegation. You
>   have to use CredSSP to delegate the user account (...)"

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/02/windows-powershell-remoting-and-delegating-user-credentials.aspx

and

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I set up the session using CredSSP, asking the admin user for credentials.

The main objective was to avoid having to enter credentials every time, so I set up a script to read the password once and save it encrypted to file (using admin's credentials) for subsequent sessions. Not an ideal solution but good enough

```
$adminuser = Read-Host "connect as username? ( default $($env:username))"
if ($adminuser -eq "") {
    $adminuser = $env:username
}
$server = "spserver"
Write-Host "connecting ..."

$passpath = "$env:USERPROFILE\cred_$($adminuser).dat"

Write-Host ("Load Credentials from $passpath")
if (Test-Path -Path $passpath) {
    $securepass = Get-Content $passpath | ConvertTo-SecureString
    Write-Host ("Loaded Credentials")
} else {
    $securepass = Read-Host "Password missing, please enter for user $adminuser :" -AsSecureString
    $securepass | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $passpath
    Write-Host ("Saving securely...")
}  
Write-Host "Connecting to remote sharepoint server..."
$cred=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "DOMAIN\$adminuser", $securepass

New-SPSession etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have patience with me as this is my first 'answer' on stackexchange, but:

I would like to share my solution using [Constrained Powershell Endpoints](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/31/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/) as described on Technet. 
Basically it sets up a new remote session configuration in which you can define a runas-user (I suppose a sharepoint farm admin will do) and a startup script.

All statements executed in this custom endpoint will be executed as the runas-account. This solution also gives you the flexibility to only present pre-created "proxy" functions, limiting what is allowed on your sharepoint.

The setup is the following.
On the sharepoint server(s):
Create a script as proposed in the link above in the 'C:\Scripts\Constrained' folder
Register-pssessionConfiguration -name 'company.sharepoint.endpoint' -StartupScript "C:\Scripts\Constrained\Sharepoint.ps1" -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -RunAsCredential (Get-Credential -Credential "domain\farmadmin") -Force -Confirm:$False
Grant the appropriate users access to the endpoint, make sure you grant them 'Invoke' permissions:

[image: SecurityDescriptor for Endpoint]

On the client: 
New-PsSession -ComputerName 'sharepointserver' -ConfigurationName 'company.sharepoint.endpoint'

Once this is set up, you can add proxy functions and all will be executed as the farm admin account.

Since a new session is created on the sharepoint server, the double-hop issue is securely bypassed and you do not have to pass credentials.

Sincerely,